# how to autogenerate the textbox value in jsp

Tags: jsp

im try to autogenerate the particular unique textbox value of a form and must increment every time on page load. I tried by using static variable, but eventually its of no use because When I close the broswer and rerun the application it starts from its initial value.

```
<%! static int i=0; %>
 <% i++; %>
<span class="label">Registration No.<m id="rbn" style="color:red">*</m></span> 
 <input type="text" name="rgno" value="CHD-<%=i%>" class="input_panel"  maxlength ="15"  id = "rgno" minlength="1" />
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

If I unserstand your query properly then You can use two approaches:

1. Use Servlet and define variable as class variable (outside of doGet() and doPost()). You will get new value until the servlet gets destroyed.
2. Create a table which will store one value(set 0 initially), when you load/refresh the page then increment the value in table by 1.